# JSF with google app engine. not sure how to call method in managedbean

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, exception

I'm using google app engine with JSF. i want to call a function when user press that button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" action="#{todo.test}" />
```

and I put todo under src->package test123.

```
package test123;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;


@ManagedBean(name="todo")
@SessionScoped
public class Todo {  

    public void test(ActionEvent event){ 
  System.out.println("lol");    
    }
}
```

but when i press button, error occurs:
sth like this:

```
 javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /Template/default.xhtml @39,38 action="#{todo.test}": Method not found: test.Todo@7929b073.test()
```

am i wrong? or do i need to do some configurations ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `actionListener="#{todo.test}"` or try:

```
public void test()
{ 
  System.out.println("lol");    
}
```

See here for more details: [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Comment: Hi @Thor, it works!! but why? I thought it should be an action event, right?

Comment: you are welcome. Do not confuse these two tags, actions is used to perform business logic and navigation task; while action listeners are used to perform UI interface logic or action invoke observation.